# Cannot change stroke and fill color of svg due to keyframe animation

Tags: jquery, svg, css-animations, fill, stroke

I am trying to edit the fill and stroke of an svg. Normally this is simple. However, this svg uses css keyframe animations to animate the stroke property.

For some reason, that prevents this from working:

```
$("#logo").css({
    "background-color": "yellow",
    "fill": "red",
    "stroke": "red"                 
});
```

The background color changes and it looks like the fill/stroke color changes too, but it is **underneath** the css animation colors (you can see the red outline slightly at the edges of the path, particularly when the svg is still grey).

This is probably tricky to understand, so I've put together a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/odk5dq4e/

Comment: Your fiddle has no animation because the CSS is not referenced. The CSS animation (if it ran) would overwrite the style change, because that's one of the things the animation does and the fill of the shape is presumably hidden by the stroke. The red outline is probably an artifact of antialiasing between the yellow background and the grey stroke.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am not sure I understand the first point, the css is scoped and inline, what is not referenced? Also, the css animation does run for me?

Comment: There's nothing that points to make-me-a-hanzi-animation-X for any X